# Java mySQL Unknown column '__' in 'field list'

Tags: java, mysql

Searched and searched, tinkered and tried every solution, but nothing works.

The Error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'stocktick' in 'field list'
```

The Table:

```
"CREATE TABLE portfolio (" 
        + "idNum INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"  
        + "stocktick VARCHAR(255),"
        + "stock VARCHAR(255),"
        + "ask DOUBLE(10,2), "
        + "bid DOUBLE(10,2), "
        + "amount INT,"
        + "fundsafter DOUBLE(10,2),"
        + "lastact VARCHAR(255),"  
        + "PRIMARY KEY(idNum))";
```

The INSERT query:

```
public void stockPurchase(String stockCode, String stockAmount){
    spent = amountInt;
    funds = funds - spent;

    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
    System.out.println(date.toString());
    System.out.println(stockAmount);
    System.out.println(stockCode);
    System.out.println(words[0]);

    try {
        //Get a connection to DB:

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, name, pw);

        prepSt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO portfolio (stocktick, stock, ask, bid, amount, fundsafter, lastact)"
                + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

        //Set the parameters:
        prepSt.setString(1, stockCode);
        prepSt.setString(2, words[0]);
        prepSt.setDouble(3, Double.parseDouble(words[1]));
        prepSt.setDouble(4, Double.parseDouble(words[2]));
        prepSt.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(stockAmount));
        prepSt.setDouble(6, funds);
        prepSt.setString(7, date.toString());

        prepSt.executeUpdate();

        System.out.println("Insert Complete");

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    fundsLabel.setText("Funds: $" + (funds));
    userPanel.remove(bpAction);
    userPanel.remove(seAction);
}
```

And the method being called:

```
stockPurchase(stock.getText(), amount.getText());
```

Everything works fine until i get to my INSERT statement, specifically, 'stocktick'. Even if i feed a straightforward string into it or try surround the string with quotes, it will produce this error. Where oh where am i going wrong?

Comment: The only reason I can think of is, maybe the program is connecting to different database than the one with table. Could you try `select * from portfolio` and `rs.getString("stocktick")` ?

Comment: *sigh* My dbUrl was pointing to a different schema, even though this would still insert into portfolio if i removed certain VALUES. Strange but resolved!